# Perl sort multiple column array

Tags: perl, sorting

The `hostlist.txt` file has only 1 col.  The prog reads `hostlist.txt` file, remove duplicate hostnames, sort the list, lookup ip address of each host in the list, and print the output on terminal.

#### hostlist.txt

```
host01
host03
host02
host01
```

#### output on terminal

```
host01,192.168.1.15
host02,192.168.1.12
host03,192.168.1.33
```

#### Program:

```
open(HOSTFILE, "hostlist.txt") or die "Couldn't open location file: $!\n";
while ($hosts = <HOSTFILE>) {
    chomp($hosts);
    push(@hostnames, $hosts);
}
close HOSTFILE;
@hostnameUnique = uniq(@hostnames);
@hostnameUniqueSorted = sort { lc($a) cmp lc($b) } @hostnameUnique; 

foreach $hostname (@hostnameUniqueSorted){
    $ipaddr = inet_ntoa((gethostbyname($hostname))[4]);
    print "$hostname,$ipaddr\n";
}
```

---

I want to do the same thing as above, except the input file `newhostlist.txt` has 3 cols. Remove the duplicate hostname, sort first col(`$type`), then sort 3rd col(`$location`), then sort 2nd col(`$hostname`), lookup ip address, and print output.
How do I process the multiple column array?

#### newhostlist.txt

```
dell,host01,dc2
dell,host03,dc1
hp,host02,dc1
dell,host01,dc2
```

#### Output:

```
dell,host03,192.168.1.33,dc1
hp,host02,192.168.1.12,dc1
dell,host01,192.168.1.15,dc2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fh, '<', "newhostlist.txt") or die "Unable to open file: $!\n";

my %unique = map {$_ => 1} <$fh>;

my @data = 
    map {join",", ($_->[0], $_->[1], (@{$_->[3]}=gethostbyname($_->[1]))?inet_ntoa($_->[3][4]):'-' , $_->[2])}
    sort {$a->[0] cmp $b->[0] ||
          $a->[2] cmp $b->[2] ||
          $a->[1] cmp $b->[1]}
    map {s/^\s+|\s+$//g; [split/,/]} keys %unique;
```

Comment: Holy, this is awesome.  I only understand the sort portion (from the research online), but hv no idea the how the other part of the code works.  One thing though, there's a "space" in front of each line starting line number 2.  How do I eliminate that?

Comment: Found another issue: if the hostname doesn't return an ip address, the script stops.  I found this piece on the Net, how do I incorporate it to your code? <br/>      my @host = gethostbyname($hostname);
    if (scalar(@host) == 0) {
        $ipaddr = "host not found - ip not avail";
    } else {
        $ipaddr = inet_ntoa($host[4]);
    }

Comment: `map` looks cool, but it's not the easiest to read, and rather hard to maintain, especially for someone who is not too familiar with perl.

Comment: Note: the `map { … } sort { … } map { … }` is a common Perl idiom known as the [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Comment: @flesk, Thanks!!  The "space" is still there, I get rid of them by adding this block at the end: foreach $date (@data) { chomp($data);}

Comment: @TLP: True. It looks cool and is fast to type up with some experience. To keep my coworkers and my future self happy, I'd never put something like this in production code though. Figured I'd add something more readable later, but it wouldn't look too different from your solution.

Comment: @user11496: I totally missed that. You can just change the bottom map to `map {chomp; s/^\s+//; [split/,/]}` or `map {s/^\s+|\s+$//g; [split/,/]}` as well.

Answer (score 3):

**ETA:** Added the check for failed ipaddr lookup.

The easiest way to handle this would be to use the diamond operator, I feel:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use ARGV::readonly;

my %seen;
while (<>) {
    chomp;  # to avoid missing newline at eof errors
    next if $seen{$_};
    $seen{$_}++; 
    my @row = split /,/, $_;
    my @host = gethostbyname($hostname); 
    my $ipaddr;
    if (@host == 0) { 
         $ipaddr = "host not found - ip not avail";
    } else {
         $ipaddr = inet_ntoa($host[4]);
    } 

    splice @row, 2, 0, $ipaddr;
    print join ",", @row;
}
```

Using [ARGV::readonly](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ARGV%3a%3areadonly) allows for somewhat safer usage of the implicit file opens used with the diamond operator.

After that, simply weed out lines already seen by using a hash, split the row, put in the value you need where you need it, and print out the reassembled row.

If you expect more complicated data in your rows, you might wish to look at a csv module, such as [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV).

Comment: +1, very readable. But why use   if (@host == 0)   instead of unless(@host) ?

Comment: @ØyvindSkaar I just modified the OPs code from a comment, it was originally `if (scalar(@host) == 0)`. `unless (@host)` works just as well, I was just pointing out that `scalar` is redundant with an array that is already in scalar context.

Comment: Might I also suggest changing `next if $seen{$_};` and `$seen{$_}++;` to just `next if $seen{$_}++;`?

Comment: @flesk You could do that, but I don't know if there's any real point to it.

Comment: @TLP: Not other than that they fit together logically, since they're part of the same "skip-if-seen-expression", but that's probably a matter of opinion.

Comment: @flesk Yes. I can see how both solutions both reduce and improve readability, both in their own ways. When in doubt, shoot for the more verbose option.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use an array of hashes for this:

```
.....
my ($type, $hostname, $location) = split /,/, $line;
push @records, {
    type => $type,
    hostname => $hostname,
    location => $location,
};
.....

my @records_sorted = sort { $a->{type} cmp $b->{type} || $a->{location} cmp $b->{location} || $a->{hostname} cmp $b->{hostname} } @records;
...
```

Comment: Thanks the sorting works, but I still need to filter the duplicate hostname.  Guess some adv Perl magic is needed. :)

Comment: Store them as a hash to begin with instead of an array of hashes and you should be able to avoid duplicates.